unable to use move_group in moveit
i have build a scara robot and i want control it with ros2 rolling but i am getting error
i am use ros2 - rolling in vmware
in error log there is nothing which says error but in rviz it shows

and robot is not moving before it was working in humble not in rolling
and it also shows this

This is the error which i have been facing
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ros2/.ros/log/2024-09-19-15-33-26-238868-ros2-60989
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
WARNING:root:Cannot infer SRDF from `/home/ros2/Kelvin6k/install/kelvin6k_scripts/share/kelvin6k_scripts`. -- using config/kelvin6k.srdf
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [60992]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [60993]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [60994]
[INFO] [move_group-4]: process started with pid [60995]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [60996]
[INFO] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner arm_controller-6]: process started with pid [60997]
[INFO] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_broadcaster-7]: process started with pid [60999]
[static_transform_publisher-2] [WARN] [1726740206.576071159] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1726740206.632430521] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.703724684] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic for robot description.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.703825858] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1726740206.709983293] [controller_manager]: Could not enable FIFO RT scheduling policy. Consider setting up your user to do FIFO RT scheduling. See [https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/controller_manager/doc/userdoc.html] for details.
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1726740206.773566513] [robot_state_publisher]: Robot initialized
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.773756428] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.778511507] [controller_manager.resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784494136] [controller_manager.resource_manager]: Loaded hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem' from plugin 'mock_components/GenericSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784558084] [controller_manager.resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784613291] [controller_manager.resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784688268] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784696555] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784704485] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784710900] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'Kelvin6kFakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740206.784724185] [controller_manager]: Resource Manager has been successfully initialized. Starting Controller Manager services...
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740206.988006482] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00149187 seconds
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740206.988115207] [move_group.moveit.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kelvin6k'...
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.009083569] [move_group.moveit.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'robot': 1 1 1
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.128394985] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.128599283] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.130876711] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.132566898] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.132599570] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping existing planning scene publisher.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.133611453] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopped publishing maintained planning scene.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.135671711] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.135760454] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.139045107] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.139079542] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.141933966] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1726740207.143326169] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1726740207.143653362] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1726740207.143683031] [move_group.moveit.moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-4] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::ParameterTypeException'
[move_group-4]   what():  expected [string_array] got [string]
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.544626479] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.726817158] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'arm_controller'
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_broadcaster-7] [INFO] [1726740209.789427590] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner arm_controller-6] [INFO] [1726740209.913125231] [spawner_arm_controller]: Loaded arm_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.923437233] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'arm_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.923645502] [arm_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.923700057] [arm_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.923731520] [arm_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740209.967792069] [arm_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740210.011447732] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740210.011537339] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner arm_controller-6] [INFO] [1726740210.046023729] [spawner_arm_controller]: Configured and activated arm_controller
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_broadcaster-7] [INFO] [1726740210.068528843] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_broadcaster-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 60999]
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740210.591562937] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740210.592554126] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.3 (GLSL 4.3)
[INFO] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner arm_controller-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 60997]
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740210.693519800] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-1] [WARN] [1726740210.901735362] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for node name: 'rviz2'. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for the logger named 'rviz2' will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
[rviz2-1] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-1]          at line 321 in /opt/ros/rolling/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740210.991502036] [rviz2.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0 seconds
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740210.992006589] [rviz2.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kelvin6k'...
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1726740214.258246693] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.293604237] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-1] [WARN] [1726740214.354613958] [rcl.logging_rosout]: Publisher already registered for node name: 'rviz2'. If this is due to multiple nodes with the same name then all logs for the logger named 'rviz2' will go out over the existing publisher. As soon as any node with that name is destructed it will unregister the publisher, preventing any further logs for that name from being published on the rosout topic.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.388050154] [rviz2.moveit.ros.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0 seconds
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.388130146] [rviz2.moveit.core.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kelvin6k'...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.421432654] [rviz2.moveit.kinematics.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'robot': 1 1 1
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.523391077] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.537537709] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.612453681] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.618574653] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.665190577] [interactive_marker_display_110136497121696]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.687255733] [interactive_marker_display_110136497121696]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740214.719708713] [interactive_marker_display_110136497121696]: Service response received for initialization
[ERROR] [move_group-4]: process has died [pid 60995, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/rolling/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_q1_yr6t0'].
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740219.567610138] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740219.693317822] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740219.693512336] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: group robot
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740219.693569744] [rviz2.moveit.ros.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'robot' in namespace ''
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740279.720446717] [rviz2.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group robot.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740416.109404282] [rviz2.moveit.ros.move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server not ready
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1726740430.470577214] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740430.470654045] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1726740430.472388219] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1726740430.473789305] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[rviz2-1] [WARN] [1726740430.492374083] [interactive_marker_display_110136497121696]: Server not available while running, resetting
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1726740430.623767309] [rviz2.moveit.ros.background_processing]: Exception caught while processing action 'Frame::changePlanningGroup': std::future_error: Broken promise
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740430.654597111] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping planning scene monitor
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1726740430.681270121] [rviz2.moveit.ros.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping planning scene monitor
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 60993]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 60994]
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 60992]
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-5]: process has died [pid 60996, exit code -11, cmd '/opt/ros/rolling/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_wu54xh92 --params-file /home/ros2/Kelvin6k/install/kelvin6k_scripts/share/kelvin6k_scripts/config/ros2_controllers.yaml'].

my launch file
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
def generate_launch_description():

    # Constants for paths to different files and folders
    package_name_ = 'kelvin6k_scripts'
 
    # Set the path to different files and folders
    pkg_share_ = FindPackageShare(package=package_name_).find(package_name_)

    urdf_file_path = 'config/kelvin6k.urdf.xacro'
    srdf_file_path = 'config/kelvin6k.srdf'
    moveit_controllers_file_path = 'config/moveit_controllers.yaml'
    joint_limits_file_path = 'config/joint_limits.yaml'
    kinematics_file_path = 'config/kinematics.yaml'
    pilz_cartesian_limits_file_path = 'config/pilz_cartesian_limits.yaml'
    pilz_industrial_motion_file_path = 'config/pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
    ompl_file_path = 'config/ompl'
    initial_positions_file_path = 'config/initial_positions.yaml'
 
    # Set the full paths
    urdf_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, urdf_file_path)
    srdf_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, srdf_file_path)
    moveit_controllers_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, moveit_controllers_file_path)
    joint_limits_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, joint_limits_file_path)
    kinematics_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, kinematics_file_path)
    pilz_cartesian_limits_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, pilz_cartesian_limits_file_path)
    pilz_industrial_motion_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, pilz_industrial_motion_file_path)
    ompl_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, ompl_file_path)
    initial_positions_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, initial_positions_file_path)

    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("kelvin6k", package_name=package_name_)
        .robot_description(file_path=urdf_model_path)
        .robot_description_semantic(file_path=srdf_model_path)
        .robot_description_kinematics(file_path=kinematics_file_path)
        .trajectory_execution(file_path=moveit_controllers_file_path)
        .planning_pipelines(
            pipelines=["ompl"],
            default_planning_pipeline="ompl"
        )
        .joint_limits(file_path=joint_limits_file_path)
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    # RViz
    rviz_config_file = (
        get_package_share_directory("kelvin6k_scripts") + "/launch/move_group.rviz"
    )
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description,
            moveit_config.robot_description_semantic,
            moveit_config.planning_pipelines,
            moveit_config.robot_description_kinematics,
            moveit_config.joint_limits,
            {'use_sim_time': True}
        ],
    )
    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    run_move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict()],
    )

    # Static TF
    static_tf = Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        name="static_transform_publisher",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "world", "base_link"],
    )

    # Publish TF
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        name="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[moveit_config.robot_description],
    )

    # ros2_control using FakeSystem as hardware
    ros2_controllers_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("kelvin6k_scripts"),
        "config",
        "ros2_controllers.yaml",
    )
    ros2_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[moveit_config.robot_description, ros2_controllers_path],
        output="both",
    )

    # Load controllers
    load_controllers = []
    for controller in [
        "arm_controller",
        "joint_state_broadcaster",
    ]:
        load_controllers += [
            ExecuteProcess(
                cmd=["ros2 run controller_manager spawner {}".format(controller)],
                shell=True,
                output="screen",
            )
        ] 

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            rviz_node,
            static_tf,
            robot_state_publisher,
            run_move_group_node,
            ros2_control_node,
        ]
        + load_controllers
    )

